# environments variables in nodejs working inside the console,log but get a error when passed a parameter to a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables

I am using nx monorepo formate and using ts for environment variables in nodejs. I have access to the variables using console.log but when i send the variable as a parameter to mongoose.connect function it doesn't work. if I give the variable straight to the mongoose.connect function it works properly.

```
exports.connection = function() {
  mongoose
    .connect('databaseUrl', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    })
    .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}; // this works
```

but

```
exports.connection = function() {
  mongoose
    .connect(environment.databaseUrl, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    })
    .then(() => console.log('connection successful'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
}; //not working
```

and

```
 console.log(environment.databaseUrl); //gives the correct value
```

Comment: Provide the error in `not working` case.

Comment: `{"error":{},"level":"error","message":"uncaughtException: dbConnection.connection is not a function\nTypeError: dbConnection.connection is not a function\n    at Module../apps/back-end/src/main.ts `

Comment: Show me where you define `dbConnection` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your string may contain some Empty Characters?

and confirm it again

```
console.log(environment.databaseUrl === 'url')
```

Comment: console.log(environment.databaseUrl === 'url') //true

Answer (score 0):

the error was due to using both ts and js in the same project, after converting the js to ts and doing the required changes. It worked